# What library does minecraft use for its 3D graphics?

Tags: 3d, rendering, lwjgl, minecraft

I know Minecraft uses the LWJGL library, but is that what allows it to have 3D graphics?

Comment: It's the first paragraph of their home page... http://lwjgl.org/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LWJGL uses `OpenGL` for rendering 2D and 3D graphics.

**OpenGL** is an API to interact with the GPU and achieve optimal hardware accelerated rendering.

It's also **cross-platform**, just like Java, making it a natural choice when it comes to graphics.